# How can I change what version of ACIV my companion app syncs with?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I used to have ACIV on pc. My XB1 came wih it, so now I play on that. My companion app still shows my pc save though. Does anyone know how to switch to another save, on a different console?

Edit: uninstalling/reinstalling does nothing. Tapping the controller icon results in it trying to sync with my pc. Nothing in settings either.

Comment: Try being logged into your Xbox and thegame, along with in settings to have it set to connect to your companion app.

Comment: Normally with Ubisoft games you are connected to them with your account. Try unconnecting/logging out of your Ubisoft account on the PC version and connect it on your XBOX1 account in game.

Comment: If I log out of the companion app and then back in, I am presented with the following screen: http://i.imgur.com/MxDYrm0.png. After I click OK, I get this: http://i.imgur.com/CC4GCb7.png. Have you logged into your uPlay account on the XBOne?

Answer (score 1):

You have to log out of the companion app, and log in with the credentials used for the XB version you are currently playing.